# Pulling data for the past few hours from a table? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is what I have right now and for some reason this displays the data for the entire dates in the table and not just the last four hours. Help is appreciated.

```
SELECT number, comments, chat_begin
                   FROM db.chats
                   WHERE ( comments IS NOT NULL ) AND
                           ( number >= 8 ) AND
                           ( chat_begin >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR ) );
```

`chat_begin` is when the chat started. It has dates as well as the time included in it. There is another column for `chat_end`.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the issue was a time zone issue.

Comment: what is the datatype type of `chat_begin`?, if `chat_begin` doens't have any time then it should't work for time interval